# Pass php variable to use in html script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

This is my page and I want to pass my php variable witch is number from my sql database to html script function. If i replace values with anything it ruin everything. If I fetch data from input it works fine. Sql part work and I can display data through php echo but i cant pass it to html script function.
I use template chart to display my data from mysql on my webpage. All i need to do is pass my php values (that part works) to .myfunc on the bottom. In other words I need to change myValues, and myValues2 with my php values (that part i didnt figure up)

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = ''; // Password
$db_name = 'esp8266_baza'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = 'SELECT vrijeme_unosa, temp, hum from temp_hum where p_key = (SELECT MAX(`p_key`) FROM `temp_hum`)';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $ptemp = $row['temp'];
        $phum = $row['hum'];    

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/meter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <br>
    <?php echo $ptemp; 
          echo $phum; ?>
    <br>
    <input id="myValues" />
    <br>
    <input id="myValues2" />
</body>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/temp.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myValues").myfunc({divFact:2,eventListenerType:'keyup'});
    $("#myValues2").myfunc({divFact:2,eventListenerType:'keyup'});

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking for. there is no that much javascript in your question. so you can try to `var ptemp = <?= $ptemp ?>;` inside your html `<script>`

Comment: problem is in the bottom of the code in script part. I use template chart to display my data from mysql on my webpage. All i need to do is pass my php values (that part works) to .myfunc on the bottom. In other words I need to change myValues, and myValues2 with my php values (that part i didnt figure up)

Comment: your explanation is still not clear to me. but probably you can try `<input id="myValues" value="<?= $ptemp ?>"/>`
    ` if you want to get those values as input value

Comment: I want my values to be passed from php to javascript directly. Not through input form. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do everything in php echo? That way you can use all variables.

```
echo "
<script>
   $jsvar = $row[varhere]
</script>
";
```